# LEFT JOIN & SUM GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by, sum

EDIT:
The result supposed to be like this:
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5lrpE.png)

I have this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mitarbeiter.mitarbnr, mitarbeiter.login, mitarbeiter.name1, mitarbeiter.name2
FROM vertragspos
left join vertrag_ek_vk_zuord ON vertragspos.id = vertrag_ek_vk_zuord.ek_vertragspos_id
left join mitarbeiter ON vertrag_ek_vk_zuord.anlage_mitarbnr = mitarbeiter.mitarbnr
left join vertragskopf ON vertragskopf.id = vertragspos.vertrag_id
left join
(
   SELECT wkurse.*, fremdwaehrung.wsymbol
   FROM wkurse
   INNER join
   (
    SELECT lfdnr, Max(tag) AS maxTag
    FROM wkurse
    WHERE tag < SYSDATE
    GROUP BY lfdnr
   ) t1
    ON wkurse.lfdnr = t1.lfdnr AND wkurse.Tag = t1.maxTag
    INNER JOIN fremdwaehrung ON wkurse.lfdnr = fremdwaehrung.lfdnr
) wkurse ON vertragskopf.blfdwaehrung = wkurse.lfdnr
left join
(
    SELECT vertrag_ID, Sum (preis) preis, Sum (menge) menge, Sum (preis * menge / Decode (vertragskopf.zahlintervall, 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,6,5,12,1) / wkurse.kurs) vertragswert
    FROM vertragspos
    GROUP BY vertrag_ID
) s ON  vertragskopf.id = s.vertrag_id
```

But I always get an error on line 21 Pos 145:

```
ORA-00904 WKURSE.KURS invalid identifier
```

The WKURSE table is supposed be joined already above, but why do I still get error?
How can I do join with all these tables?
I need to join all these tables:
Mitarbeiter, Vertragspos, vertrag_ek_vk_zuord, wkurse, fremdwaehrung, vertragskopf.

What is the right syntax? I'm using SQL Tool 1,8 b38
Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can access WKURSE.kurs in a subquery since WKURSE is itself a subquery.

Comment: What is this table ? "vertragskopf" you use it in the join condition but there is no mention of her... Please add it in your join clause...

Comment: @ellawidya do you understand my comment?

Comment: @VBoka, yes I do. I have changed and join the table vertragskopf but it still gives the same error result.

Comment: @LostReality How do I combine the sum and join in this case??

Comment: First I think you should rename the first subquery query alias. wkurse seems to be an existing table, you should not give the same alias for your subquery result, this is confusing I think.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code in table format. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: "The WKURSE table is supposed be joined already" is not clear. Moreover whatever you think is supposed to happen is not supposed to happen, because you got an error & the code doesn't make sense. So please give a simpler case & "say what you expect & why". If you don't say why you expect what you expect, with justification per authoritative documentation, then you are just asking for us to rewrite it with a bespoke tutorial with no idea what your misconceptions are.

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your question. In general, you should [edit] the question to *clarify* it, but not to include an answer within it. You should create your own answer with the code/solution you used to solve your problem, and then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to doing so). When you've solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](/help/self-answer).

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please ask exactly 1 question. PS [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `LEFT JOIN` is executed on entire dataset, and not in row-by-row manner. So there's no `wkurse.kurs` available in the execution context of subquery. Since you join that tables, you can place the calculation in the top-most select statement.

**EDIT**:
After you edited the statement, it became clear where does `vertragskopf.zahlintervall` came from. But I don't know where are you going to use calculated `vertragswert` (now it is absent in the query), so I've put it in the result. As I'm not a SQL parser and have no idea of your tables, so I cannot check the code, but calculation now can be resolved (all the values are available in calculation context).

```
SELECT DISTINCT mitarbeiter.mitarbnr, mitarbeiter.login, mitarbeiter.name1, mitarbeiter.name2, s.amount / Decode (vertragskopf.zahlintervall, 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,6,5,12,1) / wkurse.kurs) vertragswert
FROM vertragspos
  left join vertrag_ek_vk_zuord ON vertragspos.id = vertrag_ek_vk_zuord.ek_vertragspos_id
  left join mitarbeiter ON vertrag_ek_vk_zuord.anlage_mitarbnr = mitarbeiter.mitarbnr
  left join vertragskopf ON vertragskopf.id = vertragspos.vertrag_id
  left join (
   SELECT wkurse.*, fremdwaehrung.wsymbol
   FROM wkurse
   INNER join (
    SELECT lfdnr, Max(tag) AS maxTag
    FROM wkurse
    WHERE tag < SYSDATE
    GROUP BY lfdnr
   ) t1
    ON wkurse.lfdnr = t1.lfdnr AND wkurse.Tag = t1.maxTag
   INNER JOIN fremdwaehrung ON wkurse.lfdnr = fremdwaehrung.lfdnr
  ) wkurse ON vertragskopf.blfdwaehrung = wkurse.lfdnr
  left join (
    SELECT vertrag_ID, Sum (preis) preis, Sum (menge) menge, Sum (preis * menge) as amount
    FROM vertragspos
    GROUP BY vertrag_ID
  ) s ON  vertragskopf.id = s.vertrag_id
```

Rewriting the code using WITH clause makes it much clearer than select from select.

Also get the rate on last day before today in oracle is as simple as

```
select wkurse.lfdnr
  , max(wkurse.kurs) keep (dense_rank first order by wkurse.tag desc) as rate
from wkurse
where tag < sysdate
  group by wkurse.lfdnr
```

Comment: Could you please write the syntax?
if you have a look on WKURSE, I also need to combine the join with sum.

Comment: @ella widya No, I cannot. Since you don't use the calculated "vertragswert" anywhere, I cannot get why you did that calculation.

Comment: the Preis are in different currencies, like EUR, US, CAD, etc. That is why I have to calculate it with kurs to convert all Preis in EUR. So vertragswert is the total price and are in EUR.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Because of your sytax, I could get my desired result.

Comment: @ellawidya From your code I see that currency is in header table, so Sum (preis * menge) will return the desired result on line items grouped to contract_id. Then you should convert it to your currency and sum again: sum(s.amount / Decode ...).

Answer (score 0):

One option is a lateral join:

```
left join lateral
(SELECT vertrag_ID, Sum(preis) as preis, Sum(menge) as menge,
        Sum (preis * menge / Decode (vertragskopf.zahlintervall, 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,6,5,12,1) / wkurse.kurs) vertragswert
 FROM vertragspos
 GROUP BY vertrag_ID
) s
ON  vertragskopf.id = s.vertrag_id
```